# How to pass request parameter to httpintegration for Api Gateway using CDK python

Tags: python, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I have an issues while passing

```
request_parameters = {"method.request.header.User":"context.authorizer.User"}
```

Into HttpIntegation:

```
 httpintegration = _apigw.HttpIntegration(url_auth + '/logout', proxy=True, options=request_parameters({"integration.request.header.User":"$context.authorizer.User"}))
```

I got :

> TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable Subprocess exited with error
> 1 Using: cdk python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the Python example below. I suppose the **IntegrationOptions** class needs to be used.

CDK and its documentation are not reliable and there are practically no usable examples with so many defects. I am afraid CDK is not the level for general use.

```
cdk_api_method: aws_apigateway.Method = cdk_api_resource.add_method(
    http_method=str.upper(verb),
    integration=aws_apigateway.HttpIntegration(
        url=url,
        http_method=str.upper(verb),
        proxy=True,
        options=aws_apigateway.IntegrationOptions(
            request_parameters=method_parameter_set['integration_request_parameters']
            if 'integration_request_parameters' in method_parameter_set else None
        )
    )
)
```

```
"integration_request_parameters": {
    "integration.request.header.{}".format(HTTP_HEADER_X_VALIDATION_CLIENT_NAME): "'{}'".format(HTTP_HEADER_X_VALIDATION_CLIENT_VALUE)
},
```